# Is there a way to start conversation when teams tab is created using graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I am creating a `teams app` where there is an option to create a `new tab` for collaboration for individual/group by providing details like tab display title, url etc
After the tab is created, I would want to send some supporting message to describe about the tab.

Right now there is button to `start conversation`. And when you click on button some prefilled text loads along with tab title.

Is there a way I can achieve this using `graph api`, so instead of clicking on start conversation button and getting the pre-filled message, I should be able to pass the supporting message via the `graph api` ?

Or Can we customize the message shown once you click the start conversation?

Comment: Here is sample that shows a feature where user can broadcast a message to all members of organization using activty feed notification.(Graph APIs)-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/graph-activity-feed-broadcast/csharp
template-bot-master-csharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you create a Tab in Team's channel via graph api you should get 201 as success with ID of new tab.

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-type: application/json

{
  "id": "794f0e4e-4d10-4bb5-9079-3a465a629eff",
  "displayName": "My Contoso Tab",
  "configuration": {
    "entityId": "2DCA2E6C7A10415CAF6B8AB6661B3154",
    "contentUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/Orders/2DCA2E6C7A10415CAF6B8AB6661B3154/tabView",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/Orders/2DCA2E6C7A10415CAF6B8AB6661B3154",
    "removeUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/Orders/2DCA2E6C7A10415CAF6B8AB6661B3154/uninstallTab"
  },
  "sortOrderIndex": "20",
  "webUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/channel/19%3ac2e36757ee744c569e70b385e6dd79b6%40thread.skype/tab%3a%3afd736d46-51ed-4c0b-9b23-e67ca354bb24?label=my%20%contoso%to%tab"
}
```

Then you can create conversation like below

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/29981b6a-0e57-42dc-94c9-cd24f5306196/conversations
Content-type: application/json

{
    "topic": "Take your wellness days and rest",
    "threads": [
        {
            "posts": [
                {
                    "body": {
                        "contentType": "html",
                        "content": "Contoso cares about you: Rest and Recharge"
                    },
                    "newParticipants": [
                        {
                            "emailAddress": {
                                "name": "Adele Vance",
                                "address": "AdeleV@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[Ref articles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-conversations?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)